# Disable button and Forms in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, button, file-upload

Hi can someone help me with this, I dont know why my form or buttons is not disabling while uploading the file. Thank you.

```
<div>
    <form name="formImport" ng-submit="addImportFile()" class="col-lg-12 table-responsive" ng-init="loadlistimport()" novalidate="novalidate" >
            <div class="form-group"><br>
                <label for="cut_off_list" class="col-lg-12">Cut Off List:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <select class="form-control" ng-model="CutOffListTemp.id"
                                ng-options="g.id as g.cutOffList for g in CutOffListTemp"
                                required="required">
                            <option value="">-- choose type --</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
              </div><br><br>&nbsp;

                <label class="col-lg-12">FILE</label>
                <label class="col-lg-12">Select:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4" >
                    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" ng-model="file_1" class="file btn btn-default" ng-disabled="CutOffListTemp.id== Null" data-show-preview="false" required> <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!formImport.$valid">Upload</button>
                <img src="/images/332.GIF" ng-if="dataLoading" />

                </div><br/><br/>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with these properties of form $valid, $invalid, $dirty, $pristine along with Bootstrap CSS.

Check this [link](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation) along with example:

Depend on the user interaction with your form while file uploading you can set the values on these four form properties explicitly.

And for manipulating it, you can check this:

```
                 To access the form: <form name>.<angular property>
          To access an input: <form name>.<input name>.<angular property>
```